# Compare datetime in a query and perform a delete in mysql

Tags: mysql

In this table I want to delete the oldest entry for userid 1, here the oldest entry is  `ghi     10/12/2011 11:20:22`  i get the oldest entry by the datetime. How can I compare date time and do a delete in the same query. I want to compare the datetime entry for userid 1

delete from tbl_name where datetime is oldestentry and userid=1;

```
No    Name       DateTime              UserID
1     abv     12/12/2011 11:20:22         1
2     edf     11/12/2011 11:20:22         1
3     ghi     10/12/2011 11:20:22         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work in MySQL:

```
DELETE 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE No = 
      ( SELECT No 
        FROM tbl_name 
        WHERE UserID = 1
        ORDER BY datetime ASC 
        LIMIT 1
      )
```

but this does:

```
DELETE 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE UserID = 1
ORDER BY datetime ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name 
WHERE datetime = 
      (SELECT MIN(datetime) FROM tbl_name)
```

But this statement could delete multiple rows, if they have the same datetime.
Better would be something like:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name 
WHERE No = 
      (SELECT No FROM tbl_name ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Unfortunatelly mysql doesn't support this directly. But there is a workaround:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name 
WHERE No = 
      ( SELECT No 
        FROM 
          ( SELECT No FROM tbl_name ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1
          ) AS newtablename
      )
```

Comment: I am getting this error  for the second query you gave You can't specify target table 'tbl_name' for update in FROM clause

Comment: ok I googled it up. Mysql doesn't support subqueries that use the same table in delete statements. But there is a workaround - I appended it to my answer above.